# C++ dynamically convert vector to be 2D

Tags: c++, vector

Given I've already declared a regular vector as a member variable:

```
std::vector<char> vec;
```

Can I convert this to a 2D vector in the constructor of my class if necessary?

```
if(true){
    //vec becomes a 2D vector with 2 rows
}
```

At this stage the vector will have nothing in it. It'll be an empty vector of an unknown column size. Is this possible?

I don't necessarily want to have to declare it as a 2D vector to start with because if the bool is false then it means I just need the 1 row.

I thought I would be able to push_back a new vector but that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: You shouldn't be thinking this way in C++ because it is a static typed language.

Comment: "_I thought I would be able to push_back a new vector but that doesn't seem to be working_" Why not? Show what you tried and what was 'not working' about it.

Comment: You can treat a 1D vector like a 2D vector. No need to have different underlying types. Something like `vec[x + y*row_size]` would be a common approach.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A `std::vector<char>` is a different thing to a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`.

What you can do is take a 2d *view* of your `std::vector<char>`. Elements from `begin()` to `begin() + (size() / 2)` are your first row, and those from `begin() + (size() / 2)` to `end()` are your second row.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. Simply 1-D is 1-D and 2-D is 2-D. So, if you need a 2-D vector when the boolean operator is true then you can declare another 2-D vector, convert the previous one to 2-D using necessary push/pop and delete the previous one.

Code will look like this

```cpp
    // declare 1-D vector 
    std::vector<char> vec;

    if(true){
             // declare 2-D one
             vector<vector<char> >t_vec;
             // do necessary conversion
             // delete previous one
             vec.clear();
    }
```